# Understanding Entity Modeling using 3 models in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am starting to learn Spring Boot and Hibernate by building small rest services.
I am using MySQL as my database.
I am able to understand relationship annotation used in hibernate though sometimes it's tricky to write with all the verbose syntax.

Right now I am struggling with how to map 3 entities together.
The following is what I am trying to achieve.
I have a teacher entity, a grade entity, and a section entity.
Now, each Grade can have multiple sections.

```java
public class Grade {
   private String name;

   @OneToMany
   private List<Section> sections;
}

public class Section {
   private String name;
}
```

And, a teacher can teach in multiple grades or multiple sections of the same grade.

Imagine grade 1 to 5, each grade has section A to D.

Teacher, let's say John can teach Grade 1 (sec A, B) and Grade 2 ( sec C, D).

I am failing to understand the syntax to implement the above relationhip.
One way is to use another Entity called Class which will have grade and section as property.

```java
public class Class {
   private Grade grade;
   private Section section;
}
```

another way can be to use a map data structure like `Map<Grade, List<Section>> class;`

Still, I am looking for help to write it down with JPA annotations.
Any lead is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I want to mention that your question is not specific to *Hibernate*, as you can solely rely on the **JPA Specification** for this task. However, Hibernate is the default ORM for Spring and will implement the JPA spec in your program by default.

Second, I do not think that you need separate database tables for `Section` and `Grade`, and they could be modeled as simple Java Enums. In the following I made a quick sketch of a class diagram (not DB Model!) that came to my mind.

[image: class-diagram]

Note that `Grade` and `Section` are `Enums`, to restrict entering corrupted values. In the database the `Grade` and `Section` object can be mapped as either `ordinal` or `String`, [see here for reference](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa). I would recommend persisting as `String` by using this annotation `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`. With regard to mapping the one to many relationship between teacher and class, I would recommend a bidirectional relation such as shown [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many#models). However, note that there are multiple ways to model this relationship in JPA. I hope I was able to help. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer, that was fast.
I am just beginning with Spring and my questions can be very trivial, i appreciate your efforts, and I'll go through the links,

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer and the links, please accept my answer as correct, thank you :)